# Safe implementation strategy for embedded user-defined expressions

Tags: python, functional-programming, interpreter, dsl

I am designing/prototyping a Domain Specific Language... in Python, for now, at least.  The design is straightforward - but requiring support to specify an arbitrary function (the domain of which is a map from labels to integers - the range is an integer.)  In many cases, the function will merely select a label in the domain to yield a result... but I want to allow the specification of any function that could be easily (and efficiently) implemented in a general purpose programming language.

A caveat is that I want the function to be 'safe'... by this I mean:

- A 'pure' function: deterministic with no side effects. (i.e. no external state; no interaction with files, I/O, devices - etc.)
- Terminating - either successfully, or after specific (small-scale) allocated computational resources have expired.

I am keen that this function should be implemented efficiently - I expect definitions to be provided infrequently - and evaluated very frequently.  I would also like the functions to be defined using a familiar syntax.

I've considered supporting the implementation of functions in python... I'm aware that I could [impose restrictions using the eval() function](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html), and I've found the [AST module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) - suggesting an approach involving parsing to an AST, then interpreting (or verifying, prior to evaluation) the AST tree.  I've also read about [pyparse](https://github.com/mhjohnson/PyParse) and consdered implementing a bespoke, interpreted, language.

I can't help think that trying to block undesirable behaviour from eval() is to be tackling the problem "backwards" (trying to block undesirable functionality  ex-post) whereas implementing a bespoke language would involve re-inventing the wheel.

Does Python already have a safe, efficient, embeddable, expression interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

[PyPy has a sandbox.](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html)

If you're running this in the web browser (the usual place for untrusted code concerns) consider running it client-side with something like [Brython](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython). No-one cares if the user hacks his own machine.

If you do implement a bespoke interpreter, you don't have to re-implement *all* of the wheel. It's thought to be relatively safe to use `compile()` on untrusted code, but beware of large constants eating time and memory. Run the compiler in a separate process you can kill. Then you just need to write a Python bytecode interpreter that lacks access to anything important.